# Execute a command where a file is found

Tags: find, path, command

How do I execute a command where a file is found?
Consider I've an directory named `testdir` that contains the following:

```
$ ls -R testdir/
testdir/:
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5

testdir/dir1:
doc1.pdf

testdir/dir2:
file1.txt

testdir/dir3:
doc2.pdf

testdir/dir4:
file2.txt

testdir/dir5:
doc5.pdf
```

Now I want to perform an action (execute a command) where `find` finds a certain file/file type. For example let me find `*.pdf`:

```
$ find . -name '*.pdf'
./testdir/dir3/doc2.pdf
./testdir/dir5/doc5.pdf
./testdir/dir1/doc1.pdf
```

Now suppose I want to execute a command (for example say `touch file`) where the above command finds file(s). In other words, I want to create a file named `file` in each directory where at least one `.pdf` was found so that I get:

```
$ ls -R testdir/
testdir/:
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5

testdir/dir1:
doc1.pdf  file

testdir/dir2:
file1.txt

testdir/dir3:
doc2.pdf  file

testdir/dir4:
file2.txt

testdir/dir5:
doc5.pdf  file
```

How do I accomplish such a work?
May be for every time file found, `cd` to where file exist and perform a command recursively.
I know that `find` has awesome feature: `-exec` but I can't get it to work.

---

This is only an example for getting an idea about what I want to do. Broadly: How to execute an command where file(s) are found (by `find`) recursively?

Comment: welcome for tag correction if any.

Comment: your find may have the option `-execdir` for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run this command your `touch file` will be run, potentially multiple times, from the directory in which the command has been started:

```
find -name '*.pdf' -exec touch file \;
```

On the other hand, if you run this variant, each instance of the command will be run in the target file's directory:

```
find -name '*.pdf' -execdir touch file \;
```

In both cases you can see this in action by substituting the `touch file` with either `echo {}` and/or `pwd`.

---

From manpage:

> `-execdir command ;`
>   `-execdir command {} +`
>
>   Like
>   `-exec`
>   , but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started
>   `find`
>   .

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the filename's directory with `dirname` and take it from there, something like this:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec bash myscript {} \;
```

where the file `myscript` contains the following:

```
dir=$(dirname "$1")
cd "$dir"
touch file
```

Comment: it is not working, did you try it? It is making `file` only in folder it first finds

Comment: I know why it is not working, now editing your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` you could use glob qualifiers to select e.g. only `.pdf` files and via [modifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) save the directory names in an array with *unique* elements and then `cd` into each of those directories and run your command. This way you are running your command only *once* in each directory, irrespective of the number of `.pdf`s that were found in that directory:

```
dirlist=(**/*.pdf(.:a:h))
for d in ${(u)dirlist[@]}
  (cd $d && touch file)
```

or

```
typeset -U dirlist
dirlist=(**/*.pdf(.:a:h))
for d in ${dirlist}
  (cd $d && touch file)
```

---

You can further combine modifiers and qualifiers, e.g. to glob for regular files (hidden and non-hidden) with the extension `.bkp` and save unique directory names in an array:

```
dirlist=(**/*.bkp(D.:a:h))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look no further than entr:

https://bitbucket.org/eradman/entr

What you can do is let entr watch a specified directory. When find locates the file, touch a file called, say, triggerfile.txt in that directory and let entr take over.